# jquery ui - remove space between draggable elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Please find this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6PYV8/). Here sorting of elements works fine when I drop element back to "Events" area. But the problem is when I drag an element from "Events" area, the space occupied by that element won't remove. I want to remove that space or sorting when element is dragged from "Events" area. The condition is I don't want to use `sortable` of `jquery ui`. I don't want sorting in "Drop" area.

As shown in jsfiddle that there is no sorting on "Drop" area but there is a sorting on "Events" area. But the sorting on "Events" works only when an element is dropped inside it.

For example, if I drag "Event 2" and drop it on "Drop" area, the space between "Event 1" and "Event 3" remains. I want to remove that space. so the order will be Event1, Event3 and when I drop "Event 2" back to "Events", the order will be Event1, Event2, Event3.

```
$("li.ui-draggable").draggable({
     revert: "true",
 });

 $("#eventlist").droppable({
     accept: ".ui-draggable",
     tolerance: 'touch',
     drop: function (event, ui) {
         // event sorting
         console.log(':::inside drop of eventlist:::');
         var $item = ui.draggable;
         $(this).append($item);
         $item.css({
             top: 0,
             left: 0
         });

         var seen = [];

         $(this).find('.ui-draggable').each(function (index, item) {
             seen.push($(item).attr('id'));
         });
         console.log(':::seen array:::', seen);
         seen.sort();
         for (var i = 0; i < seen.length; i++) {
             $(this).append($(this).find('#' + seen[i]));
         }
     }
 });
```

**How do I remove the space in between the draggable elements or sort elements while dragging ?????**

Comment: please create a minimal jsfiddle.

Comment: Make `.sortable('disable')`

Comment: `.sortable('disable')` how will it help me for this ???-@Anup

Comment: The problem is to remove the space while dragging or sorting the elements other than the dragged one. Sorting works fine when I drop element back to eventlist.-@Anup

Comment: Waiting for your reply-@Anup

Answer (score 1):

make your #timeline droppable and remove sorting something like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ej2P/) Additionally, you can implement "on hover"

```
$('#timeline').droppable({
          accept: ".ui-draggable",      
          tolerance: 'touch',
          drop:function(event, ui){
                // event sorting
                console.log(':::inside drop of eventlist:::');
                var $item=ui.draggable;
                $(this).append($item);
                $item.css({top:0,left:0});

                var seen=[]; 

                $(this).find('.ui-draggable').each(function(index,item)
                {
                    seen.push($(item).attr('id'));
                });
                console.log(':::seen array:::',seen);    
                //seen.sort();
                for(var i = 0 ; i < seen.length ; i++){                    
                    $(this).append($(this).find('#'+seen[i]));
                }
          }
      });
```

Comment: I meant to use [http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-over "over"] or "hoverClass" to indicate your timetable "can accept" events

Comment: it's not like this. Elements can be dropped anywhere on "Drop" area. I want sorting/remove space between elements in "Events" when I drag an element. Sorting in "Events" works when I drop element back to it.

Answer (score 1):

Just for a Hint , you have to change CSS by jquery in following event :-

```
$("li.ui-draggable").draggable({                              
    revert: "true",
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
     $(this).appendTo('ul');
    // Change in CSS code
    }
 });
```

This event is fired when the item is dropped in the below DIV.

Comment: It would be great help if you provide the complete code.-@Anup

Answer (score 0):

Check this one if it is useful to you
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XvAJ4/)

```
$("#origin").sortable({
    connectWith: "#drop"
});

$("#drop").sortable({
    connectWith: "#origin"
});
```

Comment: Not like this. "Events" should be sortable in "Events" area and should be placed anywhere in "Drop" area. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6PYV8/)-@Nilesh